# Improving for loop speed in Julia 1.0

Tags: julia

I have a long vector V and a large matrix M. My purpose is in the Julia code below.

```
using LinearAlgebra
function myfunction(M,V)
    n = size(V,1)
    sum = 0
    summ = 0
    for i = 1:n-1
        for j = i+1:n
            a= [i,j]
            Y = V[a]
            X = M[a,a]
            sum += Y'*inv(X)*Y
            summ += tr(X)*Y'*Y
        end
    end
return sum, summ
end
```

```
M = randn(10000,10000)
V = randn(10000)
@time myfunction(M,V)
```

Since the vector is very long and the matrix is very large, this procedure takes a long time. I spent a long time on this issue. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just would manually unroll the calculations to avoid allocations:

```
function myfunction2(M::AbstractMatrix{T},V::AbstractVector{T}) where {T}
    n = size(V, 1)
    sum = zero(T)
    summ = zero(T)
    for i = 2:n
        for j = 1:i-1
            @inbounds y1, y2 = V[i], V[j]
            y11 = y1*y1
            y12 = y1*y2
            y22 = y2*y2
            @inbounds a, b, c, d = M[i,i], M[i,j], M[j,i], M[j,j]
            sum += (d*y11-(c+b)*y12+a*y22) / (a*d-b*c)
            summ += (a+d)*(y11+y22)
        end
    end
    return sum, summ
end
```

(note that I make explicit assumptions about `M` and `V`)

**EDIT** this is minimally faster

```
function myfunction3(M::AbstractMatrix{T},V::AbstractVector{T}) where {T}
    n = size(V, 1)
    sum = zero(T)
    summ = zero(T)
    for i = 2:n
        @inbounds y1 = V[i]
        @inbounds a = M[i,i]
        y11 = y1*y1
        for j = 1:i-1
            @inbounds y2 = V[j]
            y12 = y1*y2
            y22 = y2*y2
            @inbounds b, c, d = M[i,j], M[j,i], M[j,j]
            sum += (d*y11-(c+b)*y12+a*y22) / (a*d-b*c)
            summ += (a+d)*(y11+y22)
        end
    end
    return sum, summ
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It helps a lot. I am just wondering if parallel computing or threads will help here? Since the matrix is very large.

Comment: You could use a similar approach I have shown you in the answer to the other question.